# guice injection in static variable

Tags: java, guice, guice-3

I Have doubt about guice injection.
Is it possible to inject a @named variable value to a static variable?

I have tried

```
@Provides
@Named("emp.id")
public Integer getEmpId() {
   return 2;
}
```

and tried to inject this value to static variable such as

```
 @Inject
 @Named("emp.id")
 private static Integer id;
```

But the `id` return value null, When I removed static modifier the id gave value 1.

What is really happening here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Guice does not inject static fields by design. You can [request static injection](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#requestStaticInjection-java.lang.Class...-) but [this should be done only as a crutch](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#static-injections):

> This API is not recommended for general use because it suffers many of the same problems as static factories: it's clumsy to test, it makes dependencies opaque, and it relies on global state.

In your case you could add this to your `configure` method to have your static field injected by Guice:

```java
requestStaticInjection(Foo.class);
```

If you don't add this the Integer will be initialized to null (by default).

I have no idea why `id` was set to 1 after you removed the static modifier, however. Seems that it should have been set to 2 if your Guice module was setup correctly.

Comment: for future users , Same can be used to inject static class inside  enum also