# Mocking static private final variable using Powermock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I have a utility class which is a final class. There i have used injection for injecting LOGGER.

```
public final class Utilities {

    @Inject
    private static Logger.ALogger LOGGER;

    private Utilities() {
       //this is the default constructor. so there is no implementation
    }

    public static String convertToURl(string input){
       try{
             //do some job
          }catch(IllegalArgumentException ex){
             LOGGER.error("Invalid Format", ex);
          }
   }

}
```

While I writing unit testing for this method i have to mock LOGGER otherwise it will throw null pointer exception. How can i mock this LOGGER without creating instance of this class. I tried to whitebox the variable. But it only works with instances?

Comment: Does [the injection to static field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225179/is-it-possible-to-inject-a-cdi-bean-into-a-static-variable-in-java-ee-6) work for you?

Comment: by default guice doesn't allow static injection by design. But we can request    [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513147/guice-injection-in-static-variable)

Comment: I didn't know that. I haven't used that either, but if it's able to inject static field, maybe use it to inject a mock of logger in unit test?

Comment: Well, the easiest workaround is to make the variable package-private and put tests in the same package, but there's gotta be a better way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code works fine. To set static field you need to pass a class to `org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.setInternalState`. Please, ensure that you use PowerMock's class from the package `org.powermock.reflect` because Mockito has the class with the same name.

```
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 public class UtilitiesTest {

    @Mock
    private Logger.ALogger aLogger;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); // for case them used another runner
        Whitebox.setInternalState(CcpProcessorUtilities.class, "LOGGER", aLogger);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogger() throws Exception {
        Utilities.convertToURl("");
        verify(aLogger).error(eq("Invalid Format"), any(IllegalArgumentException.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: It needs updating. Whitebox is no longer used.

Comment: @user447607 what did you mean by “no longer used”? The class is still exist in PowerMock and will be kept. I do not have plans to remove it. May be you meant that there is another way to do it!

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify. The class still exists but it's considered part of the internal API and it's use is not recommended.

Comment: @user447607 I think you mixed `Whitebox` from Mockito and `Whitebox` from PowerMock. In PowerMock this class is public. Internal API is `WhiteboxImpl`.

Comment: Sure enough. I would have named it something else just on principle. OK, I'll fix my vote when the system unlocks it.

Comment: Change something innocuous in the answer and I can fix.

Comment: @user447607 I’ll update my answer and specify that PowerMock’s version should be used

Comment: which package is `@Mock` from ? I have suggestions from Powermock(deprecated) and mockito